# NSDictionary - Need to check whether dictionary contains key-value pair or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I just need to ask something as follow.
Suppose I am having a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *xyz=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[xyz setValue:@"sagar" forKey:@"s"];
[xyz setValue:@"amit" forKey:@"a"];
[xyz setValue:@"nirav" forKey:@"n"];
[xyz setValue:@"abhishek" forKey:@"a"];
[xyz setValue:@"xrox" forKey:@"x"];
```

Now, I need to check as follows

[xyz does contains key "b" value ?? pair or not?

Question is How?

The other question is How to just count total key-value pair?

Say for example `NSInteger mCount=[xyz keyCounts];`

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Just ask it for the `objectForKey:@"b"`.  If it returns `nil`, no object is set at that key.

```
if ([xyz objectForKey:@"b"]) {
    NSLog(@"There's an object set for key @\"b\"!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No object set for key @\"b\"");
}
```

**Edit**: As to your edited second question, it's simply `NSUInteger mCount = [xyz count];`.  Both of these answers are documented well and easily found in the [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary) class reference ([[1]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1414347-objectforkey?language=objc) [[2]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1409628-count?language=objc)).

Comment: +1 In fact, the documentation straight up says this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHCDIDJ

Comment: What if the key is present in the dictionary and its value is 0? Wouldn't we mistakenly think that the key isn't present in the dictionary at all?

Comment: @jbx72487 Dictionaries must contain objects; `objectForKey:` returns an `id` -- a pointer to an Objective-C object. If you are storing numbers, they must be ["boxed"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) into an [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Even if the NSNumber is zero or false it will be still be a valid pointer and the above code will accurately detect existence.

Comment: not working with me it return the following:   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000133a1c0'

Answer (score 4):

With literal syntax you can check as follows

```
static const NSString* kKeyToCheck = @"yourKey"
if (xyz[kKeyToCheck])
  NSLog(@"Key: %@, has Value: %@", kKeyToCheck, xyz[kKeyToCheck]);
else
 NSLog(@"Key pair do not exits for key: %@", kKeyToCheck);
```